# Split a column datetime in two columns, one for date and one for time LINUX

Tags: r, linux, multiple-columns

I have a column with DateTime in a `.txt` document (`05/28/2010  02:36`). I want to separate this column into two columns, one column for date and another one for time (Linux) for import into R.

Comment: If any whitespace is a delimiter it is already 2 columns

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I export this document into a data frame in R it is read as one single column

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to separate the date and time by a comma (`,`) or a tab. If you're using `read.csv()` you probably need the comma. Use `sed 's/  /,/1' DateTime.txt > r-import.csv` to do this (that's two spaces between the slashes), and then import `r-import.csv`. If that doesn't work, try a tab; replace `,` with `\t` in the above line: `sed 's/  /\t/1' DateTime.txt > r-import.csv`